# Storing a File in the Memory

Tags: ram

If I have a simply php file that will be accessed a **lot**, is there a way I can configure the file to be present within the RAM at all times, so rather than reloading the file from the hard drive every time, it's contents can be taken directly from the memory? Of course, writing data to the file would still require writing to the hard drive, but for reading data I want it to be as fast as possible and with less stress on the hard drive. Thanks!

Comment: ...why are you thinking it's not happening? That's normal cache behavior in Linux. (and any other sane OS, I suppose).

Answer (score 0):

Files read from disk are stored in the disk cache of Linux (RAM). You do not need to configure anything, this works out-of-the-box.

If you would like have a filesystem backed by RAM rather than a disk, then you are looking for a "RAM disk" (not to be confused with the Linux [ramdisk](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/blockdev/ramdisk.txt) filesystem). The [tmpfs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmpfs) filesystem stores all its contents in RAM (which could be swapped though).

The above is unlikely going to improve your PHP application performance. Depending on your application, you are better off with [caching the PHP response in the webserver](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_cache) (or just use static HTML/JS/whatever files to avoid PHP completely).

Comment: Thanks! It's good to know it's already cached by the disk.